# Theorem of Existence and Uniqueness Given IVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the function $F: \Bbb R^+ \rightarrow \Bbb C $ given by $ F(t, x) = (1-e^x)(x^2+x-2)^{7/9}$ and its associated IVP $$ \frac{dx}{dt}=(1-e^x)(x^2+x-2)^{7/9}, x(0) = x_0, t\ge 0.$$
There are three constant solutions $x_0 = 0, x_0 = 1, x_0 = -2$

What information can we draw from the theorem of existence and uniqueness for each of the three solutions? Where does the theorem guarantee existence and uniqueness of a solution?

I think that the function is continuous everywhere, resulting in the existence of a solution at each initial point. I feel like I am missing the point of this question though.

Comment: You may want to look at whether $F$ is Lipschitz (i.e $\partial_{y} F$ is continuous) and the effect that has on existence and uniqueness.